# How can I make a Resizable/Responsive main Image with links that stick to the size of the image within?

Tags: image, hyperlink, background, responsive, resizable

I am trying to have a base image for my website which will be responsive/resizable. However I need to pin point links to to parts of the image even if its altered or distorted.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you show your actual code?

Comment: Hi Itay, thank you for the comment, at the moment its all just in theory as this is really the first image of the webpage and all based around it, so at the moment I haven't really got much code to go on. However I remember once seeing that you can add hyperlinks to photoshop and make it responsive but I cant seem to find it again.